# android webview javascript in page not work

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I realize my javascript in the android webview page doesn't work. However, I have enabled javascript in the onCreate() function of the activity file as below. Please help. Thanks a lot.

activity file:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

main page (in this page, the js to swipe to get the panel doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LoadPageTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/customizedstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm-demos.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script scr="./js/customizedjs.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#demo-page", function() {

            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
                if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style= "overflow:hidden" scrolling="no">

<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>


<div data-role="page" id="main-page" style= "overflow:hidden" scrolling="no">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id ="maindiv" style= "overflow: auto">

        Will load diff pages here.

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" id="menu">

            <li>
            <a href="#" id = "btnA" data-rel="close">Go Page A <img src="./images/icona.png" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="#" id = "btnB" data-rel="close">Go Page B <img src="./images/iconb.png" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div><!-- /panel -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnA").on("click", function(){  

            $("#maindiv").empty();
            $("#maindiv").load("pageA.html");

        });

        $("#btnB").on("click", function(){  

            $("#maindiv").empty();

            $("#maindiv").load("pageB.html");
        });


    </script>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Loaded Page (in this page, the js code to load list item "abc" before page show doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page should be loaded</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/customizedstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm-demos.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script scr="./js/customizedjs.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
            $('#postlist').append('<li> abc  </li>');
            $('#postlist').listview('refresh');
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body >

    <div data-role="page" id="posthome">
        <div data-role = "content">
            <ul data-role='listview' id = "postlist">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My project Structure is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script scr="./js/customizedjs.js"></
<script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

You are referencing these files in your JavaScript code, actually `jQuery`. Are you sure that these files are there in your asset folder ? If not, the script will silently crash and you will not know.

This is how your structure needs to be:

```
android_asset
|_ index.html
|_ js
   |_ <your jquery files>
```

Comment: First, yes, the js files are located to the correct place. Second, even the js code in page doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Tried your webpages in a web browser first ?

Comment: Do you mean directly open the html pages with web browser in Eclipse? If that's what you mean, I did that. and script doesn't work. If not, could you teach me how to test the page in a web browser? Thans a lot.

Comment: @user2962555 I'll be glad to help. Post your directory structure :)

Comment: Hey LC, I have uploaded my project structure pic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2962555 When you run the web page in a browser, open your console and see what error you get.

Comment: Hi LC. When you say run the webpage in a browser, do you mean right click on the index.html page and open it with web browser in Eclipse? If yes, I tried to test it this way but with nothing shown in console and logcat. If that's not what you mean, please let me know how to test in a web browser. Sorry for the trouble, I am a newbie in this area. :(. Thanks again for your help.